# What are the most recent and influential breakthroughs in NLP?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language-processing, research, history, natural-language-understanding

I'm looking at the history of NLP, starting in the 1950s, with the [Georgetown–IBM experiment](http://www.hutchinsweb.me.uk/AMTA-2004.pdf).

What are examples of the most recent (e.g. in the last 5-10 years) and influential breakthroughs in natural language processing?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you take a look at the syllabus of http://cs224d.stanford.edu/syllabus.html and see what was invented in the last ~20 years. They focus on deep learning methods, and they include there almost everything important.

Among the things, which I would include into the review are:

- Word2Vec models
- Seq2Seq models

Concerning what happened in the last 5 years, i.e. since 2013, I suggest you mentioning super human performance on the SQuAD 1.1 dataset: https://rajpurkar.github.io/SQuAD-explorer/

Comment: It may be worth editing this answer to mention the transformers and related models.